# prove equality of integral in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Show that 
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x-\xi}\,dx=\text{Log}\left(\frac{\xi-1}{\xi+1}\right)$$

for $\xi\in \mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$.

I really don`t know where to start.

Comment: Indeed, the result should be $\text{Log}(\xi-1)-\text{Log}(\xi+1)$(You can deal with this just like in the real integration).  It seems to be a multi-value function. But note that for any cirle passing through $\xi$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$, the argument of $\frac{\xi-1}{\xi+1}$ does not vary when $\xi$ going around the circle. So it is a single-value function. The unknown argument can be testified by any particular $\xi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\xi=a+ib\in\mathbb{C}-[-1,1]$. For all $x\in[-1,1]$ :

$$\frac{1}{x-\xi}=\frac{x-a+ib}{(x-a)^2+b^2}$$

and so :

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{x-\xi}\,dx=\frac12\int_{-1}^1\frac{2(x-a)}{(x-a)^2+b^2}\,dx+ib\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{(x-a)^2+b^2}=\frac12\ln\left(\frac{(1-a)^2+b^2}{(1+a)^2+b^2}\right)+ibK$$

with :

$$K=\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{(x-a)^2+b^2}$$

In order to compute $K$, we can change the variable :

$$t=x-a\quad dt=dx$$

which gives, for $b\neq0$, to :

$$K=\int_{-1-a}^{1-a}\frac{dt}{t^2+b^2}=\frac1b\left(\arctan\left(\frac{a+1}b\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{a-1}b\right)\right)$$

or, using :

$$\forall t\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\,\arctan(t)+\arctan\left(\frac1t\right)=\epsilon \frac\pi2,\quad\mathrm{where :}\,\epsilon=\left\{\matrix{1 & \mathrm{if}\,t>0\cr-1 & \mathrm{if}\,t<0}\right.$$

$$bK=\arctan\left(\frac b{a-1}-\arctan\left(\frac{b}{a+1}\right)\right)$$

Finally :

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{x-\xi}\,dx=\ln\left|\frac{\xi-1}{\xi+1}\right|+i\left(\arctan\left(\frac{\Im(\xi-1)}{\Re(\xi-1)}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{\Im(\xi+1)}{\Re(\xi+1)}\right)\right)$$

This last formula is still valid in the case $b=0$. As a conclusion :

> $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{x-\xi}\,dx=\mathrm{Log}\left(\frac{\xi-1}{\xi+1}\right)$$

by definition of the complex logarithm.

Comment: this actually makes me confused now. This question is from Gamelin`s book and it came in section Jump theorem and cauchy integral formula, but I don`t see what`s the connection between the section and this solution!

Comment: @Danny: It's okay, the solution I gave is based on much more elementary concepts. It proves that there is no need to know anything about the theory of functions of a complex variable to compute this integral. Now, you should simply consider it as alternative to the required solution.

Comment: pardon me, but can you explain to me how to do it by the jump theorem, winding number, maybe? I have no idea how to use to get the integral